# kafkajs disconnect takes a long time

Tags: javascript, typescript, kafkajs

I use [kafkajs](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consumer-example) for autotests.

When calling `await consumer.disconnect()` - the command takes about 5 seconds, are there any options for a safe and fast disconnect?

```
    const consumer = this.client.consumer({
        groupId: this.groupId,
        heartbeatInterval: this.heartbeatInterval,
        sessionTimeout: this.sessionTimeout,
    });

    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({ topics: [topic], fromBeginning });
    await consumer.run({...});
    await this.disconnect(consumer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum amount of time in milliseconds the server will block before
answering the fetch request if there isn’t sufficient data to immediately
satisfy the requirement given by minBytes

```
const consumer = this.client.consumer({
    minBytes: 0,
    // or
    maxWaitTimeInMs: 0,
    ...
});
```